# Installing packages for an unattended and offline install (20.04)

Tags: 20.04, cloud-init

I am interested in using the new Autoinstall feature to create an ISO that will be offline.

I have the packages pre-downloaded and added to the ISO at /cdrom/nocloud/packages. I believe I can manually add each package to the user-data file under packages, but there are a lot. I could also programatically append them to the user-data file which is the route I am considering.

But, I am hoping there is an easier way or a less brittle way to do this?